# How to translate this regex in to a like clause

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure where one of the steps is to remove items that match a pattern

```
--Remove the databases to exclude
DELETE t
FROM #WhichDatabase t 
WHERE t.dbName like @dbExclude
```

However the pattern I want to use would be (in Regex)

```
^(chgTRK_.*)|(.*_Play)$
```

How do I achieve the same goal of passing in one string and parsing out a complex filter? I know I can do `like 'chgTRK[_]%' or like '%[_]Play'` but I am restricted because this is a stored procedure and there will not always be two parts to the filter.

Comment: Don't know about sql server, but MySql has regexp that used like `WHERE yourcolumn regexp '^(chgTRK_.*)|(.*_Play)$'`

Comment: @Dani you need to create a CLR user-defined function to do that in Sql Server

Comment: @Dani: CLR isn't allowed in many shops. And it's overkill probably when it can be done quite simply in native T-SQL by passing in each term as a row in a table, as per my answer.

Comment: CLR is discouraged at my shop, but I think that is what I may end up doing, I may just write the entire stored procedure as a CLR instead of combining sql and CLR. But I will leave the question open for a while to see if better ideas come along.

Comment: Are you asking how to translate an arbitrarily complex regex into an equivalent SQL Server where clause?

Comment: @Scott: you don't need any CLR at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a table valued parameter (SQL Server 2008) or CSV/XML/Temp table (SQL Server 2005 and earlier) to pass in your search term(s).

See ["Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond"](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) for more on this (*the* definitive article on this)

Assuming you have now loaded @DeleteConditions (table variable) with a column dbExclude

```
DELETE t
FROM
    #WhichDatabase t 
    JOIN
    @DeleteConditions d ON t.dbName like dbExclude
```

Answer (score 0):

Dani's comment gave me a idea, one solution could be is make a CLR user-defined function to make sql support Regex.

A tutorial can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) on how to make it.

Comment: As per my comment above, this may not be viable. If you want to use *real* regex not LIKE, then you have to use CLR though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing a stored procedure, you can loop over the string you use as input (though a table input would be better) and do a delete for each pattern.